# What are the most useful hotkeys/tips in the WMD editor?

Tags: discussion, editor

In the WMD editor, I recently discovered:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (link)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (graphic)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> (bold)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (italic)

What are some other useful hotkeys or tips on using WMD more efficiently?

Comment: You know that all buttons have tooltips that also tell the hotkey?

Comment: yes that's how I found the above, and just noticed the question mark that goes to this page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help (is there any formatting possible in comments?)

Comment: I **think** there is a `way` to *highlight* things in a ***`comment`***.

Comment: Let me *try* that, did it *work*?

Comment: Let me **try** that again.

Comment: FYI, there is a [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) "question."

Answer (score 7):

The hotkey is visible on hover. They should be added to the [editing-help](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Here they are (in order as in the bar):

[image: screenshot of wmd-button-row]

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> - Bold
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> - Italic
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> - Link
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> - Block Quote
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> - Code Block
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> - Graphic
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> - Ordered (numbered) List
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> - Unordered (bullet) List
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> - Heading
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> - Horizontal Line
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Undo
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Redo

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Code block)

Comment: how do you make the keys like that?

Comment: @Edward <kbd>button</kbd> or #<kbd>button</kbd>

Comment: Do you know how many times I hit this in the bloody comments and make myself sad because nothing happens? About three times a day, that's how many.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - BlockQuote
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Horizontal Line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> - Newline
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Underline