# Reference for keyboard shortcuts in WMD editor?

Tags: discussion, keyboard

Is there a reference what kind of keyboard shortcuts are available in the WMD editor control? I can't find anything on neither Stackoverflow itself (FAQ or editor help on right), nor on the WMD web site :-(

I know Ctrl-K marks a selected block as "code" - what else is available, and how can I (and any other keyboard fanatic on the Stackoverflow-trilogy-of-four sites) find out about that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hold your mouse over the icons, and the tooltip will show you the shortcut key.

Also see this question: [What are the most useful hotkeys/tips in the WMD editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/what-are-the-most-useful-hotkeys-tips-in-the-wmd-editor)