# Allowing Ctrl+k in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, code-formatting, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments)

I often use `keyword` (quotes around keywords)  to highlight some keyword or phrase  in comments. While the backticks work, the shortcut  Ctrl+K does not work in comments. Can we allow that please?

I somehow find a double click on the word (or selecting a phrase with mouse) and Ctrl+K easier than moving the cursor and putting backticks :)

Answer (score 9):

I strongly second that. And while we're at it: Why not make ctrl + L for links work as well? (Let it create the `[Link Text](http://link)` syntax.

Comment: I don't know if I agree but while we are at it, all the CTRL or CMD Something.

Comment: @Trufa many of those are block-level (headers, lists, images etc.) and obviously would destroy the current comment experience. The candidates I see are: code, link, bold and italic

Comment: Agreed!!!

Comment: @Trufa - [Here's the full list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/what-are-the-most-useful-hotkeys-tips-in-the-wmd-editor/96590#96590), (warning-self promotion); the only ones that make sense are: **CTRL-B** - Bold, **CTRL-I** - Italic, **CTRL-L** - Link, **CRTL-K** - Code, (all of which you already listed) as well as **CTRL-Z** - Undo, and **CTRL-Shift-Z** - Undo.

Comment: That said, though, it might be good to also allow quote or graphic linking/uploading, or automated list formatting....

Answer (score 0):

I agree. On Linux I only have to use ALT + H to create ``` `` ``` characters but on Windows it don't work. It would be a lot faster and easier with this feature.