# Add keyboard shortcuts for Comments editing

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments)

It's extra handy to be able to do stuff like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> when editing posts, because Markdown markup can be tedious. Can you give us this goodness in comments as well?

Comment: This is fairly similar to [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments).

Comment: See this [GreaseMonkey script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) that will enable these keyboard shortcuts in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem very similar to the feature Tim Stone lists. Speaking of keyboard shortcuts in general vs one specifically, personally I think this to be a great idea.

I'm still rather new but I have already had time to wish I could hit control B for sure :)

Better formatting tends to improve readability too; some people go the opposite way with it.