# Add shortcut key for the link in   comment box like wmd editor

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments)
>   [Add keyboard shortcuts for Comments editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78007/add-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments-editing)

Adding a shortcut key and the link box like wmd editor  for the link in comment box will be very user friendly since there is no shortcut key user have to type the `'[]()'` and this is  a little frustrating.

To clarify, I'm trying to use the shortcut key Ctrl-I that I would normally use in the question/answer editor, but I'm hoping to use this in comments instead.

Comment: What links are you trying to insert exactly? There are shortcuts for some already, but it would help to know the specific uses you have in mind.

Comment: @jmort253 i used the key ctrl+l but its not working so that i thought there is no shortcut key

Comment: What I mean is: What kind of links are you attempting to post in the comments. If you clarify that, you may find out that there *are* shortcuts for certain specific links. Like `[edit]` for the [edit] link to your post, for instance. There is `[chat]` for [chat], `[faq]` for the [faq], and I'm sure there are others that I can't quite recall at the moment but can probably find you you if you could clarify ;)

Comment: The OP is asking for keyboard shortcuts, @jmort253, not shortcuts for some common URLs.

Comment: @Mayankswami, please remember to update your question as well, when clarifying things in comments.

Comment: @Arjan - We don't have keyboard shortcuts that I know of, but if the op was trying to accomplish a specific goal with links, like linking to the faq, I thought it would be helpful to point out that shortcuts already exists for this specific sort of thing. Context helps. ;)