# How can I bump unresolved case on meta?

Tags: support, bump

I would like to ask to allow CTRL + K in in comments. However, I found I would create [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments)

How can I bump it to get it resolved/accepted/declined?

> **Editor's Note:** The procedure for getting attention for issues and requests on meta sites is different, so this is not a duplicate of other general questions that ask how to get attention for questions.

Comment: Whoops, that one is better: [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Yeah, the usual ways: editing the question, adding an answer that provides a compelling justification, or placing a bounty on it.

Comment: @Cody: I have no permissions for edit ;)

Comment: You can suggest an edit. When it's approved (assuming it is of course) the question will get bumped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Vote for it
- Place a bounty on it
- Add an answer that *eloquently* explains why this feature deserves to be implemented, and how implementing it would save fluffy bunnies from an almost certain doom.

Comment: I've heard that unicorns (drawings) can sometimes help as well....