# Way of inputting various types of information for a query/answer

Tags: support, code-formatting

The list of help related to formatting information is slightly tangled, if the Stack Overflow team device a better inputting format just by shortcuts like in Eclipse Framework, then it would be a much pleasant experience. Is there any way that can be employed to achieve that?

Comment: Like what for instance? Give an example which irritates you.

Comment: suggestive help : when ever i am trying to add code (Indentation Required) or trying to follow specific format for links, i need to follow the said format to achieve. But in the case of Eclipse, if i want to add code, i can use the help of suggestive help. I am asking that kind of User Friendliness.

Comment: A combination of Shift + ctrl leads to set of suggestive help inputs in eclipse, as i am new to these kinds of sites, sometimes i am in need of such shortcuts.

Comment: Do you know about `Ctrl` + `K`?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, so I don't know what it means. Please provide an example of input and desired output.

Comment: No, I Don't Know about Ctrl + k, can you explain about it.

Comment: @SriKrishna: CTRL+ K in an answer would indent all selected lines in 4 spaces, creating a code block. If an inline piece of text is selected, it is surrounded by ticks (`like \`so\``).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha is correct, actually CTRL+K is a "hotkey" with exactly the same result as clicking the "Code Sample" icon in the editor.

Comment: hmm, that is well said, but still i am looking for hot keys to bypass writing other meta styling for formatting. Also how can i put some static image in the comment, i have found some info on displaying image through their links, but not static ones from my own computer.

Comment: @SriKrishna Also use [@Reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/187824) so that someone can get notification when you reply.

Comment: To post images you need [at least 10 reputation points](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) it's meant as security measure against spammers.

Comment: @hims056 and @(Sha Wiz Dow Ard) Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Is this really a feature-request?

Comment: @hims056: It is. Only the feature already exists in another form.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If feature is already exists then the tag should be converted to support, discussion as OP is not aware of it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I rolled back to [support]. The question isn't explicitly asking for a new feature, it asks if there's a way to format code. As it's phrased it reads more like a [support] question, _and_ we don't want to further clutter the already very long list of pending [feature-requests] the developers have to go through, especially since this already exists, and the question was answered sufficiently (so, there's no point this reaches the devs)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Related discussions: [Is the feature-request tag being misapplied in lieu of support?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152965/is-the-feature-request-tag-being-misapplied-in-lieu-of-support) & [Should we retag the feature-request question if feature is already exists?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153029/should-we-retag-the-feature-request-question-if-feature-is-already-exists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way that can be employed to achieve that?

Yes. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is the key by whom you can format your code as `code`.

[image]

You can also use `<pre>` tag for that. You can use [backtick (`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) for single line code. Also have a look at [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Note: You can test formatting on [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/187824)

Comment: The preview should be enough for testing, but on more complicated stuff you're right, that's the use of the sandbox. :-)

Comment: `include<stdio.h>
`main(){
`printf("Nama");
`}

Comment: yes i think i am understanding the formatting. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange sites are using a rather simple editor called [WMD editor](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/), with some upgrades like support for image upload through imgur special account. (Available only for users with 10 reputation or more)

This editor is **NOT** Eclipse, it's not inspiring to be and there's no point making it as complex as this.

You have keyboard shortcuts for most available editor actions, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key plus some other key. [Here is the full list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/what-are-the-most-useful-hotkeys-tips-in-the-wmd-editor).

The [advanced help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) covers everything, if you have any suggestion to improve it go ahead and suggest with full details but just saying "it's not good please improve" is not really helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The markdown editor has shortcuts for pretty much every button on the toolbar. Hover over it & you'll see the shortcut.

Beyond this, you need to be clear on what exactly is need to "be a much pleasant experience"