# Should we retag the feature-request question if the feature already exists?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Yesterday a quite new user asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152938/187824) about code formatting. He did not know about this feature (which already exists). So he added a tag [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) instead of [support](/questions/tagged/support) (I think he wanted some help). So I edited the question and retagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) with [support](/questions/tagged/support).

But another user again retagged it to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). So [I asked him about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152938/way-of-inputting-various-types-of-information-for-a-query-answer#comment439946_152938). He replied:

> [It is (a feature request). Only the feature already exists in another form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152938/way-of-inputting-various-types-of-information-for-a-query-answer#comment439952_152938)

So my question is: Should we retag the feature-request question to support/discussion if the feature already exists?

Comment: Perhaps a mod can slap a [status-completed] onto it. But overall it's not that big of a deal I think.

Comment: @Bart Yes it's not a big deal. But the feature, he asked was very basic.

Comment: Related: [Is the feature-request tag being misapplied in lieu of support?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152965/is-the-feature-request-tag-being-misapplied-in-lieu-of-support)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally we'd find the question that led to the feature getting built in the first place and close the new question as a duplicate of that question.

If the feature wasn't based on an earlier [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), or we can't find it (Meta is chaotic, sometimes), then the easiest solution would be to flag the new request for moderation attention and ask for [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to be applied.

That said, the [question in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152938/way-of-inputting-various-types-of-information-for-a-query-answer) works as a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question as well. I went ahead and rolled back the edit. The question doesn't explicitly ask for a new feature to be built, it reads more like it's asking if the functionality already exists and how to use it, and that's exactly what a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question is.

Furthermore, SE developers keep an eye on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions and there's no reason to clutter the backlog with questions that are sufficiently answered, and don't really need feedback from SE.

Comment: _Sometimes?_ `</proactive>`

Comment: Hmm. Flagging a question is pretty nice.

Comment: So retagging such questions to `support` is okay.

Comment: @hims056 I think it's perfectly okay for the specific question we are talking about, because it didn't really describe a feature (new or existing) and because it didn't need any feedback from SE, it was already sufficiently answered. For other questions, I don't know.